# Count The occurence of a word

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python and making use of requests in python . I am asked to do loggin on xyz.com which i am able to do . And extract all the Table contents which are link to discussion . in each of these link i need to find the occurence of "The" word . how should i proceed ?My code is given below

```
tags=content2.findAll("td",{'class':'topic starter'})
for i in tags:
    thread_link=i.find('a').get('href')
    print(thread_link)
    result3=session.post(thread_link)
    content3=bs4.Beautifulsoup(result3.text,'html.parser')
    tag3=content3.find("the",count+1) 
    print(count)
```

I have to find the occurence of the in each link and print it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing this correctly. Your tag3 will be finding `the` tag. Also code is little messy. You can use regex 
for your cause. Here we will search for `the` in the result text.

```
import re
for i in tags:
    thread_link=i.find('a').get('href')
    print(thread_link)
    result3=session.post(thread_link)
    count=len(re.findall('\sthe\s',result3.text))
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use str.count, check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) for more details

```
for i in tags:
    thread_link=i.find('a').get('href')
    result3=session.post(thread_link)
    count = result3.text.count("the")
    print(count)
```

Comment: May be she want `the` not "brea`the`"

Comment: I got , Thank you . your answer was helpful . thankyou so much !